# DAW on Linux (with midi input, samples, guitar riff recording, and coming with instrument sounds)

Tags: daw, production, dj

I need a DAW (digital audio workstation) on Linux with:

```
  - a synth input (midi)
  - create and use samples from disco tunes (mp3) from the 70s
  - (optional) time to time record guitar riffs
  - come with many instruments sounds
```

All these inputs shall be mixed together to produce some music.

There are many DAWs out there, and they are very confusing to be chosen from, as I don't really know any of them.

I have tried Reason once - this would have been an amazing option, but it does not run on Linux.

Comment: probably LMMS (it’s a free and open source daw) https://lmms.io/ but linux imho is best for being used as a server.

Comment: Cockos Reaper has "experimental" support for Linux. https://www.reaper.fm/download.php#linux_download

Comment: Renoise https://www.renoise.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is Ardour:

https://ardour.org/

But it's not done with Ardour alone, you'll need to have the audio server Jack installed, which handles audio and midi connections

If you are willing to install a new/additional system you could take a look at Ubuntustudio, created for creatives:

https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/

Comment: Ardour can be used without JACK. I've been doing it that way for some time now.